# wso2 new broker type

Tags: wso2, extend, complex-event-processing, broker, wso2-cep

I have implemented a new Broker by extending the BrokerType and BrokerTypeFactory.
I wanted to deploy this new Broker to WSO2 CEP. 
I created a broker.xml and placed it in repository/conf directory

```
<brokerTypes xmlns="wso2.org/carbon/broker">    
  <brokerType name="jmsQbroker"  class="org.wso2.carbon.broker.core.internal.broker.jms.generic.GenericJMSQueueBr‌​okerType" />   </brokerTypes>
```

However this causes NullPointer exception ( in BrokerManagerAdminServer at line 149) when i browse to the Broker List page in the webconsole, and none of the brokers are shown. 
Can you please help me in understanding how can i deploy my new broker without affecting the existing ones

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues when deploying external brokers to earlier versions of CEP, This issue is fixed (from CEP 2.1.0).

you can find a guide on writing a custom broker at http://suhothayan.blogspot.com/2013/02/writing-custom-broker-for-wso2-cep.html

and you will be able to download CEP 2.1.0 RC from : https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/suho/packs/cep/wso2cep-2.1.0-RC1.zip